# Unhashable type 'list' when using list comprehension in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, typeerror

I have a set in my code called `malicious_urls` and I am trying to build a list comprehension from this.

When I run `'' in malicious_urls` I get a `False` return value. Also, I have an array `input` and when I run `[e for e in input]` I get the set back which is identical to input.

However, when I try to run `[e in malicious_urls for e in input]` to simply obtain a list of which input urls are malicious, I get an error back saying `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`?

Comment: `[(e in malicious_urls) for e in input]`?

Comment: @LutzHorn I have tried this but same issue

Comment: @chrisz untrue, I have similar list comprehensions elsewhere in my code

Comment: It is 100% true that lists are an unhashable type.  Your other list comprehensions must not try and hash lists.

Comment: `input` contains lists. Checking whether a list is in a set throws a `TypeError` because you can't compute a hash for a list.

Comment: ah sorry, I was confused about which list we were referring to in this case

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `input` is a list of lists (and it sounds like it is), your list comprehension is just missing a step.

```
[[e in malicious_urls for e in i] for i in input]
```

ex.

```
s = {'a', 'b'}
l = [['a', 'c'], ['c', 'b']]
[[e in s for e in i] for i in l]
> [[True, False], [False, True]]
```

If you want a flattened list, you can use list comprehension for that, too.

```
[item for sublist in [[e in s for e in i] for i in l] for item in sublist]
```

Comment: How does this fix the TypeError?

Comment: As far as I understand, `input` is a list and `malicious_urls` is a set. In his list comprehension he has `malicious_urls` where a single item (`e`) should be.

Comment: Since all you've done is rearrange the code, I don't see how this does anything to solve the problem. If the OP's list comprehension throws a TypeError, so does yours. All you've done is change the output - which wasn't even incorrect to begin with.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. Editing the post.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not a good place to use a list comprehension, since what you want is the intersection of two lists.

Instead, I would use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), as sets have intersection as a basic operation:

```
>>> malicious = {'badsite.com', 'reallybadsite.com', 'literallywillkillcomputer.com'}
>>> sites = {'badsite.com', 'goodsite.com', 'literallywillkillcomputer.com'}
>>> sites & malicious
{'badsite.com', 'literallywillkillcomputer.com'}
```

Comment: actually this doesn't help since I need to retain the order of the elements and obtain a boolean value for all elements in the array in the correct index to feed into a machine learning model